# Index value returning a character

Tags: python

I have created a program to count the number of each letter with a list of names. The number is then stored in a separate list. I am not trying to print the letter that has the max times used within the original list.

I have tried using the .index(max) function,  but that returns the place value. In this case[4]. The  letter would be 'E', but i cannot figure out how to get to that.

```
    names = ["Euclid", "Archimedes", "Newton", "Descartes", "Fermat",
     "Turing", "Euler", "Einstein", "Boole", "Fibonacci",
     "Nash", "Wiles", "Cantor", "Gauss", "Plato"]

alphaCount = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

print(' ord values for characters ')
print('1 ',ord('A')-ord('A'))   # 0
print('2 ',ord('B')-ord('A'))   # 1
print('3 ',ord('C')-ord('A'))   # 2
# .....
print('26 ',ord('Z')-ord('A'))

for name in names:
    for ch in name:
        x = ord(ch.upper()) - ord('A')  
        alphaCount[x] = alphaCount[x] + 1  
print('alphaCount == ', alphaCount)  

max = max(alphaCount)
most_common = alphaCount.index(max)
print("The most common letter is index value:", most_common)
```

What i have returned is the index value, but I need the letter that it relates to.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show where e.g. `alphaCount` and `names` are defined? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes sir. I have edited the original post to show the initial lists

Comment: ok, I see what you're doing

Comment: use print statementes for variables in your for-loop... its called "debugging".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest storing the counts with a `dict` instead of a `list` - that way you have a more direct relation between the letter and the count, instead of messing about with offset ascii values.

```
alpha_count = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, ...}
alpha_count['b'] += 1
...
```

Or better yet, you can use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) to initialise the counts for you. Try this solution:

```
from collections import Counter

names = [...]

alpha_count = Counter()

for name in names:
    for ch in name:
        alpha_count[ch.upper()] += 1

max_letter, max_count = alpha_count.most_common(1)[0]

print(f"most common letter, '{max_letter}', occurred {max_count} times")
```

Comment: this works. Thank you. Now I just have to wrap my head around it because I have further issues to solve from this now.

Comment: @KButler if it helps, `Counter` is just a fancy way provided by the standard library of doing the `{'a': 0, 'b': 0, ...}` dictionary I suggested first. If you're unfamiliar with dictionaries, have a read of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping). The `most_common` function takes `1` as an argument because we only want *the* most common letter (as opposed to the 2 or 3 most common), and it returns a list of pairs `[('E', 13)]` which we unpack to just the pair `('E', 13)` by calling `[0]` at the end. Then we assign the pair to two different variables.